# POSTGRESQL: ERROR: column reference "attempt" is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I get

```
ERROR: column reference "attempt" is ambiguous LINE 101: DO UPDATE SET attempt = attempt + 1;
```

I am trying to auto increment the column attempt. Alias is not supported with insert, but I am not sure what is wrong here.

```
INSERT INTO public.error_message(
    id, created_by, created_dt, modified_by, modified_dt, attempt, message_headers, message_main_topic, message_payload, message_status, message_status_code)
    VALUES (51, null, null, null, null, 1, '{
    "jsonContent": {
        "content-length": "1635",
        "message_status_code": "417",
        "cookie": "JSESSIONID=279AF4C174E6192BDAB11A067768BBD5",
        "postman-token": "f0f33e86-498f-452a-aaf6-18eb84dc5907",
        "kafka_timestampType": "CREATE_TIME",
        "message_id": "21",
        "kafka_receivedMessageKey": "null",
        "kafka_receivedTopic": "error-topic",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "kafka_offset": "33",
        "kafka_consumer": "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@5091bb5f",
        "host": "localhost:8082",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "kafka_receivedPartitionId": "0",
        "kafka_receivedTimestamp": "1552305428711",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "message_main_topic": "ldarsQCustomStatistics.1",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.6.1"
    }
}', ‘abcd.1’, '{
    "jsonContent": {
        "messageTime": 16772223422,
        "messageRev": 9,
        "businessId": "DB",
        "messageId": "55",
        "deviceId": "DB_1234_SMM",
        "assetType": "Locomotive",
        "messageType": "thirdparty-timeseries",
        "assetId": "DB_1234",
        "appId": "ThirdPartyApp",
    }
}', 1, 201)
ON CONFLICT ((message_payload->'jsonContent'->>'message_id'))
    DO UPDATE SET attempt=attempt+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid an ambiguity between the original table row and the excluded inserted row, qualify the `UPDATE`:

```
DO UPDATE SET attempt = error_message.attempt + 1
```